# iOS NSError/NSDictionary for callbacks

Tags: ios, ios7, delegates, nsdictionary, nserror

I am developing a framework which requires error callbacks. I have used delegate methods to give error callbacks to the users(developer) of the framework. Can I use *NSError* to indicate error details in the delegate method or simply use *NSDictionary* instead ? Are there any memory issues concerned here?

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nserror/ ? You'll see what's behind a `NSError` (as a `NSDictionary` in the `userInfo`). I'd suggest you use a `NSError` which is more common for the developer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of delegate methods, you should use blocks with proper error handling, something like this:

Interface:

```
typedef void(^ResultBlock)(id result, NSError *error);

extern NSString * const DummyErrorDomain;

enum{
    DummyErrorReason1,
    DummyErrorReason2
};

@interface Dummy : NSObject

-(void)doSomething:(ResultBlock)resultBlock;

@end
```

Implementation with async NSURLConnection:

```
NSString * const DummyErrorDomain = @"DummyErrorDomain";

@interface Dummy ()

@property (strong) ResultBlock resultBlock;
@property NSURLConnection *connection;
@property NSMutableData *responseData;

@end

@implementation Dummy

-(void)doSomething:(ResultBlock)resultBlock
{
    self.resultBlock = resultBlock;
    self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"dummyURL"]];

     self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    self.resultBlock(nil,error);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    self.resultBlock(self.responseData, nil);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
-(void)usage
{
    Dummy *dummy = [[Dummy alloc] init];

    [dummy doSomething:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if(result){
            // everything went fine
        }else{
            // error handling
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: I am using delegates in order to connect to server,fetch data, sort it and send different type of data to the developer via different delegate methods. Server calls are asynchronous.
That is the reason to use Protocols. Would the above motive be achieved through block method ?

Comment: You better start learning what blocks can do. If you don't know how to use blocks, you miss out on an awful lot to make your code easier to write and understand.

Comment: Yes, that is totally possible. You save the resultBlock, and you call it from the async delegate method.

Comment: Since a lot of delegate methods use `NSError`, I don't know why would block be better in all cases. It really depends on what you want to achieve and how you design your code/app. I'm not saying that blocks or delegates are better than the other, but still, there are two logical powerful.

Comment: @KaszásDávid Can you provide some tutorial on how to use blocks for asynchronous workflow ?

Comment: I edited my answer, I think you get the hint of it. You should do some more digging to fully understand and concept of the blocks and add it to your toolbox.

Comment: @KaszásDávid Thank you for the example above! It is very helpful.
I would like to ask whether I will encounter any memory issue if I use multiple blocks for different method implementation?

Comment: No. But if you will, it won't be because of multiple blocks

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is helpful indeed.